# Error en firebase has no exported member 'auth'

Tags: firebase, angular5

Al intentar conectar una base de datos de firebase con angularjs me sale este error

```
ERROR in node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,10): error TS2305: Module '"F:/inventario/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has no exported member 'app'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,15): error TS2305: Module '"F:/inventario/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has no exported member 'auth'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,21): error TS2305: Module '"F:/inventario/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has no exported member 'database'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,31): error TS2305: Module '"F:/inventario/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has no exported member 'firestore'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,42): error TS2305: Module '"F:/inventario/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has no exported member 'functions'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,53): error TS2305: Module '"F:/inventario/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has no exported member 'messaging'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,64): error TS2305: Module '"F:/inventario/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has no exported member 'storage'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/firestore.d.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"F:/inventario/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has no exported member 'firestore'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/interfaces.d.ts(2,10): error TS2305: Module '"F:/inventario/node_modules/firebase/app/index"' has no exported member 'firestore'.
```

esto es lo que tengo en `environments/environment.ts`

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAtlSxhbhUIrAPzV9Uzg8LtE9Sl-9KVd1g",
    authDomain: "testing-1575a.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://testing-1575a.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "testing-1575a",
    storageBucket: "testing-1575a.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "929737689620"

  }
};
```

el `app.module`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { AngularFireModule } from "angularfire2";
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore'
import { environment } from "../environments/environment";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

el `component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from "angularfire2/firestore";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/observable";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

interface Note {
  content: String,
  hearts: Number,
  id?: String
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  notesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Note>;
  notes: Observable<Note[]>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.notesCollection = this.afs.collection('notes');
    this.notes = this.notesCollection.valueChanges();
  }
}
```

y, finalmente el `component.html`

```
<div *ngFor='let note of notes | async'  >
  <h3> {{note | json}} </h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola Lograste solucionar?, yo también tengo este problema, al parecer es la incompatibilidad de las versiones del Firestore2 y firebase.
Yo tengo estas versiones:

- "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.10"
- "firebase": "^5.0.4"

Sin embargo No me da problema alguno cuando trabajo con estas versiones:

- "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.7"
- "firebase": "^4.12.1"

Saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias, por problemas de la universidad no había podido ver tu comentario, pero lo acabé de ver y me funcionó perfectamente, muchas gracias